# Seeing scripts in unix box - Information Server

Tags: ibm-information-server

We did some changes in login.wpcs to change the user name provided in UI to lower case as LDAP login was not case sensitive. Now the issue is we are not able to login as 'Admin' and we have not given any of the roles permissions to change the ACG/Roles etc. Also Screen level access is not permitted to any other role. How do I now login into the company and change the login script. I tried to mount the document store '/scripts' folder but it also didn't help. I am not able to see the scripts in the unix box mounted location.

Answer (score 0):

Once login.wpcs script is messed up can't even get to the UI to clean up. Try the following procedure
 
1. From a working MDM CE environment of same version, take a Selective Environment Export which just contains the /scripts/login/Login.wpcs file from docstore. Same can be achieved by running the following script snippet in sandbox

```
var envObjList = new EnvObjectList();
envObjList.setTypeToExport("DOC_STORE");
envObjList.addObjectByNameToExport("/scripts/login/Login.wpcs", null, "CREATE_OR_UPDATE");
var result = exportEnv(envObjList, "export_20120501_234914.zip");
out.println("result: " + result);
```

2. Run sh $TOP/bin/importCompanyFromZip.sh  --company_code= --zipfile_path=
 
Now try logging in.